# Listing all the groups to which a user belongs in macOS

Tags: macos, user-account, group

I want to know the groups of some user.

`$dscl . list /groups` **filterByUSer** `theFindUser`

Is this possible (even if I have to enumerate all the groups and then filter by user) in a straightforward manner?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try the command given below.

```
id -Gn [user]
```

On my Mac, the output from `id -Gn davidanderson` is given below.

```
staff everyone localaccounts _appserverusr admin _appserveradm _lpadmin _appstore _lpoperator _developer _analyticsusers com.apple.access_ftp com.apple.access_screensharing com.apple.access_ssh 2 1
```

The delimiter could be changed from a space to a comma by entering the following.

```
groups="$(id -Gn davidanderson)"
groups="${groups// /,}"
echo "$groups"
```

Here, the output would be as follows.

```
staff,everyone,localaccounts,_appserverusr,admin,_appserveradm,_lpadmin,_appstore,_lpoperator,_developer,_analyticsusers,com.apple.access_ftp,com.apple.access_screensharing,com.apple.access_ssh,2,1
```

I am using High Sierra, macOs 10.13.4 and a bash shell.

Comment: Is there a way to add a delimiter between the groups?

Comment: You mean other than a space? Like a comma maybe?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I ended up using `id` on its own. It printed the group id, the name in parentheses and used a comma as a separator. This would only work for looking up the current user. That solved my problem though.

Comment: Any idea which API in which Framework of MacOS provides this information? I need this, but from my Cocoa code - and I can't find an answer...

Comment: Could you not just [Execute a terminal command from a Cocoa app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app)?

Answer (score 5):

To list all the groups to which a user belongs, type:

`id [username]`

`[username]` argument is optional. By default, the logged in user is assumed. The output will include the numeric user id `uid`, and the list of all the groups along with their group id `gid`, of which the user is member of. The first group in the output is the user's primary group.

To list just the group names type:

`id -Gn [username]`

To list just the group numbers type:

`id -G [username]`